# Site redirects to index.php after being open while making calls to an API using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

I have built out a site that is constantly refreshing data using an AJAX call to an external API. The AJAX call uses JSONP to grab a JSON string of data due to the cross-domain restrictions involved with browsers.

The site's function is to stay open on a bigger monitor so that our help desk can be notified about how many tickets are in their queues. The site works fine some some undetermined amount of time, usually between 30 minutes to an hour. But for some odd reason it breaks and tries to redirect to "index.php", which doesn't exist. I'm not sure what is causing this.

I have relevant code below. I've spent some time in narrowing it down to that specific javascript function. I have spent some time on Google looking for answers, but have come up empty.

Perhaps someone has some insight into what is happening? Or does anyone know of any good website monitoring tools I can use to observe what is happening?

To add, the "token" part of my AJAX call is valid in my site, but I just cleared it out here for security purposes.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WALLBOARD</title>
    <link href="Content/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/wallboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_hardware" class="div_normal span6">
        <h1>Hardware</h1>
        <div id="span_hardwareTickets">-</div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_atschool" class="div_normal span6">
        <h1>AtSchool</h1>
        <div id="span_atschoolTickets">-</div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_network" class="div_normal span3">
        <h1>Network</h1>
        <div id="span_networkTickets">-</div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_software" class="div_normal span3">
        <h1>Software</h1>
        <div id="span_softwareTickets">-</div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_openTickets" class="span3 div_normal">
        <h1>Open Tickets</h1>
        <div id="span_openTickets">-</div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_newTickets" class="span3 div_normal">
        <h1>New Tickets</h1>
        <div id="span_newTickets">-</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        grabParature();
    </script>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function grabParature() {
var url = "https://s3.parature.com/api/v1/5406/5426/Ticket";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: true,
    jsonp : "_callback_",
    jsonpCallback: "theData",
    data: {
        "_status_type_": "open",
        "_pageSize_" : "500",
        "_output_" : "javascript",
        "_token_" : "##################################"
    },
    success: function (results) {
        var openTickets = 0;
        var newTickets = 0;
        var atschoolTickets = 0;
        var hardwareTickets = 0;
        var softwareTickets = 0;
        var networkTickets = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < results.Entities.Ticket.length; i++)
        {
            var queue = "";
            var status = results.Entities.Ticket[i].Ticket_Status.Status.Name["#text"];

            if (results.Entities.Ticket[i].Ticket_Queue != undefined) {
                queue = results.Entities.Ticket[i].Ticket_Queue.Queue.Name["#text"];
            }

            if (status === "Open") {
                openTickets++;
            }
            else if (status === "New") {
                newTickets++;
            }

            if (queue === "Hardware") {
                hardwareTickets++;
            }
            else if (queue === "Atschool") {
                atschoolTickets++;
            }
            else if (queue === "Network") {
                networkTickets++;
            }
            else if (queue === "Software") {
                softwareTickets++;
            }
        }
        $('#span_openTickets').html(openTickets);
        $('#span_newTickets').html(newTickets);
        $('#span_hardwareTickets').html(hardwareTickets);
        $('#span_atschoolTickets').html(atschoolTickets);
        $('#span_networkTickets').html(networkTickets);
        $('#span_softwareTickets').html(softwareTickets);

        setInterval(grabParature, 10000);
    }
});
```

};

**EDIT**

I changed setInterval(grabParature, 10000), to setTimeout(grabParature, 10000) as per Ryan Wheale's suggestion. I still get a redirect to index.php.

Answer (score 4):

Try not setting an interval.  You should only have to setTimeout().  The interval would eventually stack up a bunch of these calls so that after about 30 minutes I can see you running out of memory as you would have about 180 ajax calls going out at the same time.  Not sure why the redirect is happening  - I would expect the browser to freeze... hard to tell without testing out.

Comment: I'm testing it now. I forgot about the subtle differences between setTimeout() and setInterval().

Comment: I changed it to setTimeout(grabParature, 10000), I'm still getting the redirect to index.php.

Comment: Can you open in Chrome, open the developer tools (CTRL/CMD + i), switch to the "Timeline" tab and hit the record button. Make sure you are on the "Memory" graph and see if you are running an uphill slope of memory consumption.  After that, can you start a new session, switch to the "Network" tab, and then hit the record button again.  Eventually, you will have index.php as a line item.  You want to check out the responses of the last AJAX requests immediately *before* the redirect.

Comment: Here is my memory timeline. It looks like it's fine up until about 11 minutes: [Memory Timeline](http://imgur.com/BDPw0p5). I'm currently recording my Network activity. Thanks for your help by the way. I knew about the Chrome Developer tools, but I learned something new about them today.

Comment: On the last call before it hits index.php, the response of my AJAX request is "Canceled". It looks like I'll need to contact the API provider.

Comment: I recommend reading through the information for the cancelled AJAX request and the 2-3 preceding (working) AJAX requests.  You will want to compare the Request Information as well as the Response - try and find a discrepancy.

Comment: Also, AJAX calls are cancelled when a redirect happens, so the cancelled request is likely not the problem.  Still, check out the preceding requests for anything unusual.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35159/discussion-between-ryan-wheale-and-ryan-duffing)